# display confirmation after successfully update when click the button using ajax in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

My Problem is how to Display the confirm message after the button click without refreshing the page.. my code is working but when I click the button the page is alway refreshing. I knew how ajax works with this but Im newbie in ajax. and one more, after submiting the button my url change to admin_home/librarian_msg instead of http:localhost/webitefoler/admincontroller for example.

in view admin_page.php

```
  <?php echo form_open('admin_home/librarian_msg');
   echo form_label('Librarians Message');?>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="the_librarian">   </textarea>
    <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Update',"class='btn btn- success navbar-btn'");?>
                <?php echo form_close();
                ?>

                <div class="alert alert-success">
                <?php echo $message_display;?>
   <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;     </a>
```

in controller admin_home.php

```
 public function librarian_msg()
  {
    $data['title'] = 'some text here';
        // Check validation for user input in SignUp form
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('the_librarian', 'Message',  'trim|required|xss_clean');
 $message = $this->input->post('the_librarian');
 $result = $this->home_admin_database->librarian_msg_insert($message);
 if ($result == TRUE) {

 $data['message_display'] ='Message Updated';
  $this->load->view('admin_page', $data);
  } else {
  $data['message_display'] = 'Update Failed';
   $this->load->view('admin_page', $data);
 }

 }
```

in model
home_admin_database.php

```
public function librarian_msg_insert($data) {
$message = array(
           'message' => $data,
        );
// Query to insert data in database
 $this->db->where('lm_id', '1');
$this->db->update('librarians_message', $message);
 if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
 return true;
 }
 else {
 return false;
 }
 }
```

help me...

Comment: add `event.preventDefault()` in ajax function

Comment: oh i see.. so wont upload automatically right?

Comment: You used submit button so whenever you clicked it will submit your form. To prevent it you should add peventdefault or use normal button instead of submit button

Answer (score 1):

Try this java-script code to submit your form:-
User your form id instead of #your_form_id in below code.
Use your status message div id instead your_status_message in below code.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
         $("#your_form_id").submit(function(e)
        {
            var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
            var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
            $.ajax(
            {
                url : formURL,
                type: "POST",
                data : postData,
               beforeSend: function(){
                   // Append status message to the div
                   $('#your_status_message').append('Sending....');


               },
              complete: function(){
                   // Append success message to the div
                   $('#your_status_message').append('Complete....');
              },              
                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
                {

                   $('#your_status_message').append('Success....');
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                {

                }
            });
            e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
            e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
        });
</script>
```